# Magento 2 Custom admin module not working

Tags: magento2, extensions, 404, admin-controller, adminmenu

I have created my custom module for order export and this is working fine in my magento 2.5 and magento 2.6 but this OR any other module is installed in my magento 2.2 it will not show in admin and when i try to access this with URL it will show 404.

Comment: Have u tried clearing cache and running reindexing. Please also clean browser cache once

Comment: Is it enabled? php bin/magento module:status what errors in browser console? Enable PHP errors in index.php uncomment option.

Comment: @BartZalas Yes, this is enabled and no error is shown in a browser console.

Comment: What about system or exception? And error Apache log?

Answer (score 0):

@Divyarajsinh: You can try this:
 1. logout from admin and 
 2. Run setup:upgrade and flush magento cache.

I hope this will be helpful for you.